# LinkedIn boolean search param 'geoUrn'

Tags: linkedin-api, geo, urn, boolean-search

I'm trying to build boolean search query from my app. Code worked fine before, but now there are problems with the location parameter.

my old code generates this string (it worked well before):

> [https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?facetGeoRegion=["ca:0"]&keywords=((html5))&title=((automation))](https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?facetGeoRegion=%5B%22ca:0%22%5D&keywords=((html5))&title=((automation)))

now LinkedIn generates this string:

> [https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?geoUrn=["101174742"]&keywords=((html5))&title=((automation))](https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?geoUrn=%5B%22101174742%22%5D&keywords=((html5))&title=((automation)))

What is the parameter 'geoUrn' and how can I get a list of relations country-geoUrn?

Comment: Take a look at this [Bing Geo Migration Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/bing-geo-migration-guide). In particular the example API about [querying a country](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/advertising-targeting/bing-geo-migration-guide#another-example-when-querying-a-country)